# Pygame flip keeps flipping at the wrong time

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my image flip on pygame horizontally but I am slightly confused by how it works

I have tried to use the the pygame.transform.flip(bool_x, bool_y) function but it appears to take two boolean parameters which is quite confusing to understand and I am trying to make my player so that when the x_speed is negative or zero (going left) the player will be facing left and when the x_speed is positive (going right) the player will be facing right.

```
class Player:
    [...]

    def turn_around(self, direction):
        if direction == "left":
            self.picture = pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False)

        elif direction == "right":
            pass

while True:
    [...]

    if keyboard_in == False:
        if joystick:
            movement = 3
            axis_x, axis_y = (joystick.get_axis(0), joystick.get_axis(1))
            if abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
                player_one.speed_x = movement * axis_x

    if player_one.speed_x >= 0:
        player_one.turn_around("left")

    if player_one.speed_x < 0:
        player_one.turn_around("right")
```

The actual results are that the player constantly keeps flipping left or right when the player is moving and when I let go of the joystick it appears to face a random direction:

[image: the pic]

sorry if the diagram is difficult to understand it was difficult to get an exact picture because the sprite was flipping left and right really quickly

Comment: `True` means only `make flip`. It doesn't matter if you move right or left direction - flip doesn't know it and it doesn't care of it. You should flip only when `direction` is different than `previous_direction`

Comment: flip has two values because it can flip left-right (first value) and top-down (second value)

Comment: you could create two images at start - ie. `image["left"], image["right"]` - you can load first image and use flip to create second image. And later use `self.picture = image["left"]` or `self.picture = image["right"]` or shorter `self.picture = image[direction]`

Comment: Ok I am now having a problem with the fact that my sprite has many costumes that need to be flipped but this does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 images. One for the left and one for the right:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__():
        # [...]

        self.right = self.picture
        self.left = pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False)
```

Choose the image dependent on the direction:

```py
class Player:
    # [...]

    def turn_around(self, direction):
        if direction == "left":
            self.picture = self.left

        elif direction == "right":
            self.picture = self.right
```